# What is the difference between "look into" and "look at" when used in figurative meaning?

Tags: expressions, differences, prepositions, american-english, business-language

> Thank you for sending me the introduction of your company. We will
>   "look into"/"look at" it later.

What is the difference between "look into" and "look at" when used with a figurative meaning in the above sentence?

What I would like to express is that I will probably consider something later (it was needed sometime in the future) and will not consider it seriously in the short term. Which phrase is more appropriate? What is the polite way to say it?

Comment: ***To look at  sth*** is to ​think about a ​subject ​carefully so that you can make a ​decision about it  as in : 
*Management is ​looking at ​ways of ​cutting ​costs.*  - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-at-sth - ***to look into*** means to inquire into; investigate as in *The police looked into the disturbance.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/look+into - I think "look at" is more appropriate in your context.

Comment: Another way to express the distinction that Josh61 identifies in his comment above is that "look into" implies "investigate," whereas "look at" implies "consider."